# NetBeans compiling error for JWS app

Tags: java, web-services, web, netbeans, java-web-start

I created an app with various `.jar` files; I wanted to execute this program using JWS but NetBeans launches an Building Error, and gives me 2 errors:

```
C:\Proyecto OUMA\ouma.administracfdi.Reader\nbproject\jnlp-impl.xml:253: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Proyecto OUMA\ouma.administracfdi.Reader\nbproject\jnlp-impl.xml:845: jarsigner returned: 1
```

Then I refer to the lines that the errors gave me:

```
<antcall target="generate-jnlp"/>

<sign-jars keystore="${jnlp.signjar.keystore}"            storepass="${jnlp.signjar.storepass}" 
                keypass="${jnlp.signjar.keypass}" alias="${jnlp.signjar.alias}" mainjar="${dist.jar}" destdir="dist"
                codebase="${jnlp.codebase.value}" signedjarsprop="jnlp.signed.jars"
                **componentsprop="jnlp.components">
```

I'm signing the app using the Self-sign option in NetBeans.

Another rare thing that happens: when I don't use the signing option, the app doesn't give the building error.

Thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing "java.util.zip.ZipException" during the signing?  I believe I was getting your same error from bad .jar files in my "lib" folder.  They were .jar files with duplicate pom.properties and pom.xml files.  (Seems like it's a maven problem...)  To fix this I had to delete the duplicate files in the zip/jar files.  (I used "7-Zip" for this.  Just open in 7-zip, select the duplicate file(s) and hit the "delete" key.  You won't be able to extract because the zip/jar file has multiple of the same filename/location.)